# yum install hadoop-0.20-osg - missing dependency

Tags: java, hadoop

I m using rhel -5 and install hadoop using yum command

yum install hadoop-0.20-fuse

error :
[root@localhost ~]# yum install hadoop-0.20-fuse

Loading "security" plugin

Loading "rhnplugin" plugin

Loading "installonlyn" plugin

This system is not registered with RHN.

RHN support will be disabled.

Setting up Install Process

Setting up repositories

Reading repository metadata in from local files

Parsing package install arguments

Resolving Dependencies

--> Populating transaction set with selected packages. Please wait.

---> Package hadoop-0.20-fuse.i386 0:0.20.2+737-31.osg.el5 set to be updated

--> Running transaction check

--> Processing Dependency: libjvm.so for package: hadoop-0.20-fuse

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Missing Dependency: libjvm.so is needed by package hadoop-0.20-fuse
**how to resolve missing dependency problem . plz help i m a newbie...**

Comment: install java and set classpath properly

Comment: @AurA yes.first i install java(jdk 1.6.0_37) successfully and set path in /etc/profile file.